# Ace Editor Mode for Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have found Ace editor has a [JS Regex highlighting rules](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/js_regex_highlight_rules.js) file, and I've been trying to implement this as a separate mode, so that only regular expressions are highlighted in Ace.
I've created the following main file:

```
// lib/ace/mode/js_regex.js
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";

    var oop = require("../lib/oop");
    var TextMode = require("./text").Mode;
    var Tokenizer = require("../tokenizer").Tokenizer;
    var JsRegexHighlightRules = require("./js_regex_highlight_rules").JsRegexHighlightRules;
    var MatchingBraceOutdent = require("./matching_brace_outdent").MatchingBraceOutdent;
    var CstyleBehaviour = require("./behaviour/cstyle").CstyleBehaviour;
    var CStyleFoldMode = require("./folding/cstyle").FoldMode;

    var Mode = function () {
        this.HighlightRules = JsRegexHighlightRules;

        this.$outdent = new MatchingBraceOutdent();
        this.$behaviour = new CstyleBehaviour();
        this.foldingRules = new CStyleFoldMode();
    };
    oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);

    (function () {

        this.lineCommentStart = "//";
        this.blockComment = {start: "/*", end: "*/"};

        this.getNextLineIndent = function (state, line, tab) {
            var indent = this.$getIndent(line);

            var tokenizedLine = this.getTokenizer().getLineTokens(line, state);
            var tokens = tokenizedLine.tokens;

            if (tokens.length && tokens[tokens.length - 1].type == "comment") {
                return indent;
            }

            if (state == "start") {
                var match = line.match(/^.*[\{\(\[]\s*$/);
                if (match) {
                    indent += tab;
                }
            }

            return indent;
        };

        this.checkOutdent = function (state, line, input) {
            return this.$outdent.checkOutdent(line, input);
        };

        this.autoOutdent = function (state, doc, row) {
            this.$outdent.autoOutdent(doc, row);
        };

        this.$id = "ace/mode/js_regex";
    }).call(Mode.prototype);

    exports.Mode = Mode;
});
```

This doesn't seem to work, it keeps the previous syntax highlighter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works fine for me. Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: I do not. It doesn't highlight at all, it stays on the previous mode.

Comment: do you call `session.setMode("ace/mode/js_regex")`?